# Getting a NullPointerException error when starting application using resource adapter for Websphere MQ (TLS/SSL)

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, resource-adapter

Scenario: Our web application is connecting to an MQ server using a resource adapter for Websphere MQ. As I’m setting this up to use TLS/SSL, I added the sslCipherSuite in my activation property during the setup of my ra. Tried starting the application after doing the change but I’m getting a NullPointerException. Upon digging into the stack trace error is:

```
exception: { message: “Cannot invoke “java.net.URL.openstream()” because “resource” is null”, frames: [ { class: “com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CipherSpecBean”, “method”: “getCiphers” } ]
```

If my understanding is correct, is it because its trying to use the cipherSuiteMapping for IBM JRE? MQ Server is v9.

Thank you.

As we are not using the IBM JRE, I tried setting a system property com.ibm.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings to false but I’m still getting the same error. Is there something here that I’m missing?

Answer (score 0):

The class CipherSpecBean static initializer code wants to load resource file "com/ibm/mq/jmqi/internal/ciphermappings.json" from its Jar file. Problem here is that the thread's context classloader used does not see the resource file. One solution would be to assure a TCCL is set that can load the resource file.